# How do I Implement Pinch Zoom in following code in android

Tags: java, android, uiimageview, pinchzoom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Pinch and Zoom Image in Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210443/android-pinch-and-zoom-image-in-activity)

I have to implement pinch zoom functionality in following android code. If possible please provide code too.
please mention that where do i have to implement that particullar code in this file.

```
enter code here
 public class ImagedisplaytestActivity extends Activity {
        private ImageView leftArrowImageView;
        private ImageView rightArrowImageView;
        private Gallery gallery;
        public int selectedImagePosition = 0;
        private GalleryImageAdapter galImageAdapter;
        private String bitmapImg = "";
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            setupUI();
        }

 private void setupUI() {
                Intent i = getIntent();
                Bundle extras=i.getExtras();
                bitmapImg = extras.getString("BitmapImage");
                selectedImagePosition = extras.getInt("Pos");

                leftArrowImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.left_arrow_imageview);
                rightArrowImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right_arrow_imageview);
                gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
                leftArrowImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (selectedImagePosition > 0) {
                            --selectedImagePosition;
                        }
                        gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, false);
                    }
                });

                rightArrowImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (selectedImagePosition < DetailView.bitmapURL.size() - 1) {
                            ++selectedImagePosition;
                        }
                        gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, false);
                    }
                });

                gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                        selectedImagePosition = pos;
                        if (selectedImagePosition > 0 && selectedImagePosition < DetailView.bitmapURL.size() - 1) {

                        leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_disabled));
                            rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_disabled));
                        } else if (selectedImagePosition == 0) {
                        leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_enabled));
                        } else if (selectedImagePosition == DetailView.bitmapURL.size() - 1) {
                            rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_enabled));
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    }
                });

                galImageAdapter = new GalleryImageAdapter(this, DetailView.bitmapURL);
                gallery.setAdapter(galImageAdapter);
                if (DetailView.bitmapURL.size() > 0) {
                    gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, false);
                }
                if (DetailView.bitmapURL.size() == 1) {
                    rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_disabled));
                }

            }

            public class GalleryImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
                private Activity context;
                private  ImageView imageView;
                private List<String>  plotsImages;
                private ViewHolder holder;
                public GalleryImageAdapter(Activity context, List<String> plotsImages) {
                    this.context = context;
                    this.plotsImages = plotsImages;
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return plotsImages.size();
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    return 0;
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        holder = new ViewHolder();
                        imageView = new ImageView(this.context);
                        imageView.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
                        convertView = imageView;
                        holder.imageView = imageView;
                        convertView.setTag(holder);
                    } else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    }
                    holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                    holder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

                    try {
                        bitmap = DownloadImage(plotsImages.get(position));
                        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        bitmap = null;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                            return imageView;
                }

                private class ViewHolder {
                    ImageView imageView;
                }


                 private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL){
                        Bitmap bitmap = null;
                        try {
                            InputStream in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
                            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                            in.close();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return bitmap;
                    }

                    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException{
                        InputStream in = null;
                        int response = -1;
                        URL url = new URL(urlString);
                        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
                            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
                        }
                        try{
                            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                            httpConn.connect();
                            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex){
                        throw new IOException("Error connecting");
                        }
                        return in;
                    }

            }

        }
```

**any help will be appriciated. Thank you.**

Comment: Rather than just copy and paste code, why not invest some time to learn what you are trying to do?  There are LOTS of articles here and elsewhere on implementing pinch zoom.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375817/android-pinch-zoom