# How to zoom in a bitmap with high resolution?

Tags: android, pinchzoom

I am trying to implement an image viewer using `TouchImageView`.

- `TouchImageView` is placed in a Fragment.
- And I set a large image(2500x3000) to this `TouchImageView`,
  (loading with inSampleSize=8).
- Then I pinch zoom-in the image, it is displayed at low resolution.(It's no wonder.)

However, I want to display a high resolution image at zoom-in, like Android Gallery app. How to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210443/android-pinch-and-zoom-image-in-activity and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630373/android-image-view-pinch-zooming

Comment: I checked the links. but Its not very useful for me.I am using TouchImageView(https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView), and it works well. So I can pinch zoom-in/out.

Comment: Use webview to display image.

Comment: I had already tried WebView. But webview image quality is not good at zoom-in.